# Using a Wildcard at end of String

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to find a way to use a wildcard in an if statement. So I have values like this: 07/22/2012 (dates) and I then want it to do:

```
if (date = "07/" *) { alert("test"); };
```

it must also only use the wildcard after the 07 as in the middle it can have: 06/07/2012

Any advice appreicated, thanks simon. Also I can use jquery if anyone knows a easier way in that.

Comment: You really should explain your use-case. String wildcards could be implemented using the regexp function, but comparing dates is done much better using the DateTime functions.

Comment: There are several ways you can go with this. Regexp, converting to date and inspecting date, splitting the string to only compare against first two digits, etc. jQuery doesn't have any tools that will help with this.

Comment: so, you are trying to search for the value "07/" at the beginning of a string?

Comment: For dates, compare as dates. Why use strings?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) function to check that particular part of the string:

```
if (date.substring(0, 3) === "07/") { alert("test"); };
```

---

That said, I agree there may be bigger problems with your use case. If you are trying to verify dates you really should be using date functions instead of trying to validate strings.

Answer (score 0):

Use [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)/[substr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr):

```
if (date.substr(0, 3) == "07/")
```

to check whether the string begins with that sequence. In very modern JS engines you can also use `date.startsWith("07/")` (also when you [shim it](https://github.com/paulmillr/es6-shim)).

For more complex matching, you might want to use a regular expression. "beginswith" would look like this:

```
/^07\//.test(date)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to match a string to a particular pattern, you should use [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

If you want to test that a string begins with a certain substring, you'd use a RegExp such as:

```
/^07\//
```

- `/` at the beginning and end delimit a Regular Expression literal
- `^` matches the beginning of the string, it prevents the pattern from matching within the date, such as `'06/07/08'`
- `07` matches the string `'07'`
- `\/` matches a `/` character, the `\` character is used as an escape so that the regex isn't closed, similar to how quotes within a string need to be escaped with `\` (e.x. `"\""`).

The way to check in an `if` statement would be to use the `test` method:

```
if (/^07\//.test(yourDate)) {
    ...do stuff...
}
```

This is all unicorns and rainbows for pattern matching strings, but if you're working with dates a lot, you should be parsing the date into a `Date` object and managing it through an object, rather than trying to perform complex pattern matching.

Answer (score 0):

Can I recommend that if you are trying to manipulate dates you use a library like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com).

For example to check that a date's month is July do:

```
// month starts at 0 so July => 6
var month = 6;
var d = moment("07/22/2012", "MM-DD-YYYY");

if( d.month() === month ) alert("test");
```

Example [here](http://jsbin.com/opesom/1/edit)